# jQuery, call part of an array object from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have am building a javascript system which has some options. The system pulls information in from JSON. Based on the option I want to trigger a specific part of the array object and I don't want to have to use eval()

Ordinarily I would do that like this.

```
$.each(data.data, function () {
    console.log(this.images.small_image.src);
}
```

Now that works fine until I want to use a variable to do that, the variable would be replacing the "small_image" part and can be anything from "large_image", "scaled_image" and so on.

So What I want to do

```
var image_variable = 'small_image';
$.each(data.data, function () {
    console.log(this.images. + image_variable + .src);
}
```

I am unsure if this is possible, but hoping someone has some ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not sure if this is even a valid question, considering this is the really basics of JavaScript, but here you go.*

You can read an object value by passing the key inside square brackets `[ 'key' ]`.

```
var image_variable = 'small_image';

$.each( data.data, function( ) {
    console.log( this.images[ image_variable ].src );
} );
```

You should probably make sure the key is defined first though, with `instanceof Object` or so. This will avoid errors in your script and enables you to extend your own error handler to explain what went wrong to the user.

```
if ( this.images[ image_variable ] instanceof Object ) { }
```

Comment: thanks, i was preceding it with a . which was causing my issue, thanks for th detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Use string.replace.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```
var image_variable = 'small_image';
$.each(data.data, function () {
    console.log(this.images.src.replace(large_image, image_variable)); //something like that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can access object properties through strings. That being said, this would do the exact same:

```
this.images.small_image.src;
this[images.small_image].src;
```